# what is the best method to connect to google analytics API via Node.js and Express?

Tags: node.js, express, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am wondering what is the best way to connect to my google analytics API using Node.js. I have tried the method below but I get trivial errors and struggle to find documentation to help me out. Just wondering if this method is the best way. Thank you for reading!

I am trying to visualize google analytics data on a web application. So, the first step I figured would be to request certain data from the google analytics API. I am working in Node.js and Express. I am getting a no file found error after the googleAuth.getClient call. Here is my current code:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {auth: googleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const responses = require('../lib/responses');
const auth = require('../lib/auth');

const router = Router({ mergeParams: true });

// Use the auth middleware to require a token
// for each non whitelisted request
router.use(auth.authMiddleware);

const viewId = '*********';

router.get('/data', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const client = await googleAuth.getClient({
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    ]
    });
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }

    console.log("client ", client)

 const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A${viewId}&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=2018-08-28&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews`;

  try {
   const outcome = await client.request({ url });
  }catch(err){
     console.log(err);
  }

  return responses
                .success ( res, outcome.data )
                .error ( );
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://flaviocopes.com/google-analytics-api-nodejs/

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
 const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL, null, 
 process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, scopes)

 const view_id = 'XXXXX'

  async function getData() {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwt,
      'ids': 'ga:' + view_id,
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
  })

   console.dir(result)
  }

  getData()
```